# Android how to install apk file stored in assets folder

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I am able to install an apk file stored on sdcard using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/mnt/sdcard/downloads/Sample.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

How can I install an apk file stored in assets folder? Is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use following code to write file on sdcard:
[How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard)
and from that path install by following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Whats the condition when the phone has no sdcard but only internal memory?